# Does Neo4j brings the whole graph of nodes to RAM, to do a single query?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

To run a single query does Neo4j brings the whole Graph of Nodes to RAM and execute the query?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j uses a pagecache (you can define the size of this in your neo4j.conf) to cache parts of the db to memory, so the more the graph is queried, the more warmed up the pagecache gets (there are also procedures, like APOC's warmup procedure, that can help when run at db start).

That said, only the parts of the graph that are touched by a query will get into the pagecache (provided they're not in there already).

If you PROFILE your query and you see a massive number of db hits and rows in the query plan, then it could be that a large portion of the graph is being accessed and cached.

If your query is a graph-wide query touching much of the graph, that may be expected.

However, if the query is meant to only touch a smaller part of the graph, it may be a sign that your query isn't tuned (such as by a lack of indexes to find starting nodes for matches, or other issues in the query itself), and that you may need to make changes or get help to streamline the query. Try the neo4j-users slack for advice with cypher queries, if that seems to be the problem.